# Can someone tell me what %.1f means

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me what %.1f means?

Example:

```
v_alt = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.alt 

print("Value: %.1f meters" %v_alt)
```

Answer (score 2):

It means the floating point number will be printed with one number behind the comma

```py
>>> x = 12.34567
>>> print('Value is %.1f' % x)
Value is 12.3
```